# VB.Net has AxVSFlex7 when add referent to VSFlex7.ocx

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I use VS 2015 and I create a VB.net project. Then I add VSFlex7.ocx component, it automatic generate AxFSFlex7 in the references, see more at attachment image plese
I do not know why. What is "Ax"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35egl.png)
Thank you!

Comment: It is the wrapper for the ActiveX component. It is automatically added because you need it too in order for it to work. This is completely normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the wrapper around your activex control. You don't directly use the VSFlex7 control, you use this wrapper instead.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27219&seqNum=9

Comment: I have a large project. It used VSFlex7. Now I wanna to convert it to vb.net. I do not wanna modify source

Comment: if you're not going to modify your app you're not going to get any gain from moving to .net. The changes should be minimal. Try asking the vendor of vsflexgrid what their recommended upgrade method is.

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi